# Javascript - Make element clickable and toggle off other button

Tags: javascript, toggle

How can I make the plus/minus sign clickable?  It's not right now...
How can I make the other button off (dropdown) if open when I click on the second button?

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".dropbtn").append('<span class="adl-signs">&nbsp;+</span>');

function ctaDropMenu(e) {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

function toggleSigns(e) {
  $(e.target).find('.adl-signs').html(function(_, html) {
    return $.trim(html) == '&nbsp;+' ? '&nbsp;-' : '&nbsp;+';
  });
}

$(".dropbtn").click( function(e) {
  ctaDropMenu(e)
  toggleSigns(e)
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

FIDDLE = https://jsfiddle.net/neuhaus3000/jf1zetLw/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jf1zetLw/11/). I tried to simplify your code as much as possible, and used jQuery wherever I could.

```
function changeText(text) {
  return (text.indexOf('+') >= 0) ? 'Click Me -' : 'Click Me +';
}

$(".dropbtn").click(function() {

  var $this = $(this),
    $dropdownActive = $('.dropdown-active');

  /* changing the text of the active button (if any) */
  $dropdownActive.text(changeText($dropdownActive.text()));

  /* hiding the content under the active button (if any) */
  $('.dropdown-content', $dropdownActive.parent()).toggle('show');

  if (!$this.hasClass('dropdown-active')) {

    /* changing the text of the clicked button */
    $this.text(changeText($this.text()));

    /* showing the content under the clicked button */
    $('.dropdown-content', $this.parent()).toggle('show');

    /* adding this class to the clicked button */
    $this.addClass('dropdown-active');
  }

  /* removing this class from the active button */
  $dropdownActive.removeClass('dropdown-active');
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var $dropdownActive = $('.dropdown-active');

    /* changing the text of the active button (if any) */
    $dropdownActive.text(changeText($dropdownActive.text()));

    /* hiding the content under the active button (if any) */
    $('.dropdown-content', $dropdownActive.parent()).toggle('show');

    /* removing this class from the active button */
    $dropdownActive.removeClass('dropdown-active');
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any troubles. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much!  There's one little problem.  When we click on the opened drop down button to close it, it doesn't.  It keeps re-opening.  Thanks a million!!!  The text will be different from button to button though... :)

Comment: Super! Thank you!!! Regarding the text, it will be different from button to button... ;)  Merci! :)

Comment: Yes!  This is amazing!  Kind Regards.

Comment: Accepted... But I need a little modification to be able to add any text on the button. :)  Thanks again!!!

Comment: I would need to append "+" or "-" on .dropbtn instead of adding the all Click Me text... But I can't fix this... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134775/discussion-between-blaze-sahlzen-and-jacques-goudreau).